# serializing a json response using web service

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, drop-down-menu, knockout.js

As I'm new to knockout, web services and all this things, I'm trying to populate a dropdownlist using knockout js and a web service.

the Html code is

```
<body>
    <select data-bind="options: printers"></select>
</body>
```

and the javascript block is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = {
            printer: ko.observable(),
            printers: ko.observableArray()
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "PapersDDLs.asmx/getPrinters1",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                viewModel.printers(response.d);
            }
        });

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>
```

the web service I call is

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class PapersDDLs
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function getPrinters1() As String
       Dim db As New DataClassesDataContext
       Dim printers = From p In db.Printers Select p
       Dim values As New List(Of PrinterItem)
       For Each pr In printers
          values.Add(New PrinterItem(pr.BrandModelName, pr.Id.ToString()))
       Next
      db.Dispose()
      Return New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(values)
   End Function

   End Class
```

The problem is that the string that is returned is made character by character.

Any help will be valuable

Thanks!

Comment: So is this not working?  Are you getting any errors in the javascript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in your web service is slightly incorrect. You don't need to do the Javascript serialization yourself. Because you have marked the web service as a System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService, the content of the response will automatically be serialized as JSON.

The method signature should be:

```
Public Function getPrinters1() As List(Of PrinterItem)
```

and the return statement should be:

```
Return values
```